# Creat Java to open or link other program

Tags: java

Please help me out!

I want to make a program that after I click or selected it will open other program by using JAVA.

I know how to create selection or button but I don't know how to put event after it has been click or selected to open directly to other program for example like:

I have button name "MS.Word" and after click, it with directly open Microsoft Word.

Is it possible to do that? please show me a way. 
Thank.

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-run-another-application-from-java.html

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you're being very unclear about what your actual problem is.

Comment: use Runtime.exec() and point it to your executable or script

Comment: oh..sorry about that.
well, I am trying to make something like this:
[link](http://postimg.org/image/nr0ium9cz)

so after I click on those button it will open those program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.

Have a look at using [exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) this Executes the specified string command in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

[Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: I don't seem to understand. please give me an example.

Comment: public String listDir() throws Exception {
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "/usr/bin");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true); //send stderr to stdout
 Process p = pb.start();
 p.waitFor();
 BufferedInputStream processInputStream =  new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 IOUtils.copy(processInputStream, writer);
 return writer.toString();
}